# DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'librvnpal' when starting RavenDB 4.2 on windows 7 x64. How to correct this?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb4

VC redistributable package is installed.

Here is the detail of the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sparrow.Server.Platform.Pal' threw an exception. ---> Sparrow.Server.Platform.IncorrectDllException: librvnpal version might be invalid or not usable on current platform. Initialization error could also be caused by missing 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package' (or newer). It can be downloaded from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'librvnpal' or one of its dependencies: The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
   at Sparrow.Server.Platform.Pal.rvn_get_pal_ver()
   at Sparrow.Server.Platform.Pal..cctor() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Sparrow.Server\Platform\Pal.cs:line 66
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sparrow.Server.Platform.Pal..cctor() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Sparrow.Server\Platform\Pal.cs:line 83
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sparrow.Server.Platform.Pal.rvn_get_current_thread_id()
   at Sparrow.Utils.NativeMemory.ThreadStats..ctor() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Sparrow\Utils\NativeMemory.cs:line 77
   at Sparrow.Utils.NativeMemory.<>c.<.cctor>b__25_1() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Sparrow\Utils\NativeMemory.cs:line 18
   at System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1.GetValueSlow()
   at Sparrow.Utils.NativeMemory.AllocateMemory(Int64 size, ThreadStats& thread) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Sparrow\Utils\NativeMemory.cs:line 114
   at Sparrow.Json.ArenaMemoryAllocator..ctor(SharedMultipleUseFlag lowMemoryFlag, Int32 initialSize) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Sparrow\Json\ArenaMemoryAllocator.cs:line 69
   at Sparrow.Json.JsonOperationContext..ctor(Int32 initialSize, Int32 longLivedSize, SharedMultipleUseFlag lowMemoryFlag) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Sparrow\Json\JsonOperationContext.cs:line 366
   at Sparrow.Json.JsonOperationContext.ShortTermSingleUse() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Sparrow\Json\JsonOperationContext.cs:line 306
   at Raven.Server.Utils.Cli.RuntimeSettings.TryGetRetainVMSettingValue() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Raven.Server\Utils\Cli\RuntimeSettings.cs:line 21
   at Raven.Server.Utils.Cli.RuntimeSettings.Describe() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Raven.Server\Utils\Cli\RuntimeSettings.cs:line 69
   at Raven.Server.Utils.Cli.RavenCli.GetInfoText() in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Raven.Server\Utils\Cli\RavenCli.cs:line 551
   at Raven.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-4.2\42009\src\Raven.Server\Program.cs:line 93
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues where found regarding the above error, and are fixed here : https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/pull/9365

They will be available in the upcoming 4.2.1 release (or later this week in a nightly build after PR is merged).